# Split char vector of 0 and 1 to double

Tags: matlab, char

I have a char vector which looks like this:

```
char_vec = '001100';
```

And I want to make it just a double vector:

```
double_vec = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0];
```

I gave an example with only 6 values, but actually I have a very long char vector (approx. 2000 values). So the splitting should work on any vector length.

Can you help me please with this problem?

Comment: Please show the code you already have. This is not a code-writing service, but maybe somebody can help you if you show what you have tried yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `double` and subtract the ascii value of character '0'

```matlab
char_vec = '001100';

double_vec = double(char_vec-'0')

double_vec =

     0     0     1     1     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.  Can you exaplint please or send link about this part: -'0'. I am not sure that I understand it.

Comment: Try it without the `-'0'` part. You'll see that the array comes up with values of 48 and 49. These are the ASCII values of the characters '0' and '1', respectively. If you subtract the ASCII value of '0', you'll get numeric 0 and 1.

Comment: edited to subtract the character value before converting to double. Likely doesn't matter, but may avoid performance and roundoff issues.